# SUMIF and FIND combined?

Tags: google-sheets

Here are my columns:

Column A has values representing screen resolutions such as "1366x768"

Column L has a formula to pull the first half of the numbers (the pixel width) out of the text string `=VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND("x",A2)-1))`

Column N has my criteria; literal values that can go in the formula like ">=1600"

Column O has the SUMIF formula `=SUMIF($L$2:L,N3,$B$2:B)`

I'd like to have only one formula so I can do away with the separate column for the number values.

Tried this but got "0" in the cell:

`=SUMIF(VALUE(LEFT(A2:A,FIND("x",A2:A)-1)),N3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but please try (if only to satisfy my curiosity!):

```
=arrayformula(SUMIF(VALUE(LEFT(A2:A,FIND("x",A2:A)-1)),N3,$B$2:B))
```